# My program is not computing the right output, and I'm not sure why

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, class, jgrasp

I've been staring at this program for hours, maybe a second perspective could help.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Examples

{
private int numbers[]; 
private String result;

     public Examples()
        {
     numbers = new int[10];
         Arrays.fill(numbers, 42);
        } 

        public Examples(int[] array)
        {
        numbers = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
        }


 public void setNumbers (int numbers) 
    {                                           
    this.numbers = new int[numbers];
    }
 public int [] getNumbers()
 {                                      
    return numbers;
 }



public  String toString()
{
    String result = new String();
    int i;                                  
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        result = numbers + "\t";
        return result;
}
```

I'm supposed to create a class that stores integer and then prints out a certain output depending on what static void main method I am provided with. The one I am currently on is,

```
{
   public static void main( String [] args )
   {
      int i;
      FunkyNumbers funNumbers, moreFun;

      System.out.println("FunkyClientA:");
      System.out.println("Test default constructor and toString method");
      System.out.println();

      funNumbers = new FunkyNumbers();
      System.out.println("toString result from funNumbers:");
      System.out.println( funNumbers.toString() );
      System.out.println();

      moreFun = new FunkyNumbers();
      System.out.println("toString result from moreFun:");
      System.out.println( moreFun.toString() );

   } // end of method main

} //
```

The result is supposed to be 
Test default constructor and toString method

toString result from funNumbers:
42  42  42  42  42  42  42  42  42  42

toString result from moreFun:
42  42  42  42  42  42  42  42  42  42

however I get,
Test default constructor and toString method

toString result from funNumbers:
[I@6e1408

toString result from moreFun:
[I@e53108

Comment: wheres your `FunkyNumbers` class??

Comment: Where happens in your FunkyNumbers constructor?  That is the one that is being called...

Comment: We can help you, after you show us your code of the `FunkyNumbers` class...

Answer (score 2):

**Issue: You are always assigning a new value to `result` and not appending.**

Better to use `StringBuilder` as :

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        result.append(numbers + "\t");
    return result.toString();
```

If don't want to use `StringBuilder` then

```
    String result = new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        result = result + numbers + "\t";//append in result
    return result;
```

Also make sure the method is available in `FunkyNumbers` class. If not accessible there, then move/copy there.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
        result += numbers[i] + "\t";
```

in your `ToString()` method

Include the code to your `FunkyNumbers` class and i might be able to provide better feedback.

Comment: That will not affect the output, as OP is printing instance of some `FunkyNumbers` class.

Comment: @RohitJain maybe FunkyNumber extends Example,

Comment: @SamIam thats a big mayb.. :P

Comment: well that certainly helped, but I'm still slightly off. I get

Comment: @user1804737  I bet you tried to create a new line in your comment, didn't you?  It's normally best to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

An array in java is an object. So the variable funNumbers has as value not the array but a reference which points to the address in your memory where the array is located. When you use `toString()` you print this memory address on your screen and not the array as a String. You should use a `StringBuffer` instead to "convert" the array to a String.

```
private static String convertArrayToString(int[] a) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            sb.append(a[i]);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

You can also use `Arrays.toString(arg)` to "convert" your array to a String. As argument you give your array and you get a String representation of your array back. If your array is multidimensional use `Arrays.deepToString(arg)` instead.